# How to track currently downloaded files from server?

Tags: php, linux, video, hosting, cpanel

I'm using shared hosting(hostgator).
I have site with video content like youtube written in `php`.
Implemented via direct links to `mp4` files and html `video` tag.

I want to limit connections for file downloads(plays) to around 350.
Because if I have more than ~350 connections hostgator blocks my site.
Is there any way to do that?
Any other suggestions how to deal with this situation will also be helpful.

Comment: Create a PHP page that handles the download then count.

Comment: i've tried this but videos aren't playing via html video tag with this approach

Comment: can you place some code that you may have tried or that already exists

Comment: You've got to point the HTML video tag at your PHP file for that to work.

Comment: As it has been said, I think you should create a PHP file (front controller), an .htaccess that sends all the requests to the PHP file, and it's the PHP file that counts the connections and returns the video.

Comment: Also about this approach. would i be able to track closing connections? for example. video started downloading and user closed the page. in this case could i track connections-1 ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a php script which handles the actual file download. If the script is executed, increment your download counter and if the file is sent completely to the client, close the connection.

To detect if the file is completely sent, you should send the file in small chunks and check after each transmitted chunk, if  the connection is still open.

To do this

- send the correct mime-types and http headers
- use `ignore_user_abort` to keep the script running if the client closes the connection
- send the file in small chunks and check after each chunk if the connection is still alive. `ob_flush` and `flush` are used to keep the output buffer empty. `connection_status` or `connection_aborted` to test if the connection is still open.
- after the whole file is submited, decrement your connection counter

In addition to this, you might also implement `HTTP_RANGE`, to resume incomplete downloads. This should be important especially for video downloads, if you want to seek somewhere in the middle of the stream.

Below a little `.htaccess` that rewrite all the requests for the PHP file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ yourFile.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Below the PHP file

```
// code to increment the counter..
// increment_counter(); ...

// Use the request path (URI) to choose what file to send.
$filename = 'video.mp4';
$size = filesize($filename);
$f = fopen($filename, 'rb');

if (!$f) {
    // error...
}

ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");

while (!feof($f)) {
    echo fread($f, 8192);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    if (connection_status() != 0) {
        // download aborted... decrement the counter
        // decrement_counter(); ...
        break;
    }
}

fclose($f);

// download completed - decrement counter
// decrement_counter(); ...
```

This script is pretty simple, but should give you an idea. You might add more logic (as said above HTTP_RANGE) or send other headers, but this should give you a good starting point.

**References**:

Below the links to the documentation of the functions that could be less known.

[connection_status](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php)

[ignore_user_abort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: That's interesting, but I think to be an answer a code sample would be useful.

Comment: @AnthonyB I added an example

Comment: @Philipp i've tried your solution. noticed one problem with it(atleast in firefox). when you pause the video. browser stops downloading it but does not close the connection. or its just because of the HTTP_RANGE?

Comment: I've upvoted. This example is useful and shows how to return the video chunk by chunk.

Comment: @Philipp i've implemented ranges also using this script https://gist.github.com/ivankristianto/8000648 and it seems that connection remains open until a leave the page. even if the file finishes downloading